# Magento products are not displayed in front end home page

Tags: php, magento, product

I have installed a theme for magento store in order to display the products which i have added recently i have written this code in the content of the home page :

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

using this it is displaying the preloaded products of theme , to display the products of my category i changed this to :

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="39" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But now it is giving me an error like :

```
There are no products matching the selection.
```

and same error it is showing when a category is clicked in the navigation bar.

Comment: I have all cleared the cache and reindexed the entries..Products are in stock and also has start as new date to and from set.

Comment: please check all possibility like product is in stock,product is enabled ,category active

Answer (score 0):

Create new root category (Set it as default category for your current web store) and assign all category products to root category(products must be both category and root category).try this..